# SerializationError while scrapng the data and push to elastic search

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, beautifulsoup

Below is the code

i am trying to **scrape** the data and try to push to elastic search

```
import re
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es_client = Elasticsearch(['http://localhost:9200'])

#drop_index = es_client.indices.create(index='blog-sysadmins', ignore=400)
create_index = es_client.indices.delete(index='blog-sysadmins', ignore=[400, 404])

def urlparser(title, url):
    # scrape title
    p = {}
    post = title
    page = requests.get(post).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
    title_name = soup.title.string

    # scrape tags
    tag_names = []
    desc = soup.findAll(attrs={"property":"article:tag"})
    for x in range(len(desc)):
        tag_names.append(desc[x-1]['content'].encode('utf-8'))
    print (tag_names)

    # payload for elasticsearch
    doc = {
        'date': time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
        'title': title_name,
        'tags': tag_names,
        'url': url
    }

    # ingest payload into elasticsearch
    res = es_client.index(index="blog-sysadmins", doc_type="docs", body=doc)
    time.sleep(0.5)

sitemap_feed = 'https://sysadmins.co.za/sitemap-posts.xml'
page = requests.get(sitemap_feed)
sitemap_index = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
urlss = [element.text for element in sitemap_index.findAll('loc')]
urls = urlss[0:2]
print ('urls',urls)
for x in urls:
    urlparser(x, x)
```

my error:

```
SerializationError: ({'date': '2020-07-04', 'title': 'Persistent Storage with OpenEBS on Kubernetes', 'tags': [b'Cassandra', b'Kubernetes', b'Civo', b'Storage'], 'url': 'http://sysadmins.co.za/persistent-storage-with-openebs-on-kubernetes/'}, TypeError("Unable to serialize b'Cassandra' (type: <class 'bytes'>)",))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `json serialization error` appears when you try to indicize a data that is not a primitive datatype of javascript, the language with which json was developed. It is a json error and not an elastic one. The only rule of json format is that it accepts inside itself only these datatypes - for more explanation please read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_json_datatypes.asp). In your case the tags field has a `bytes` datatype as written in your error stack:

```
TypeError("Unable to serialize b'Cassandra' (type: <class 'bytes'>)
```

To solve your problem you should simply cast your tags content to string. So just change this line:

```
tag_names.append(desc[x-1]['content'].encode('utf-8'))
```

to:

```
tag_names.append(str(desc[x-1]['content']))
```